# Downloading Images by Count

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using async to download uri's on each request and close when a count is reached, however I discovered that i'm still running into the same problem of the files not being downloaded properly and exiting before it reaches it's max. What's the best way to resolve this? As always, thanks for the help.

```
async.each(images, function (image, callback) {
  var uri = image.attribs.src;
  var random = (Math.random() * (3 - 1) + 1) | 0;
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream(outFile);
  request(uri).pipe(stream);
  stream.on('finish', callback);
  console.log('[' + chalk.green('✓') + ']' + ' wrote image ' + count);
  count++;
  if (count === commander.max) {
    process.exit(0); 
  }
  sleep.sleep(random);
}, function (error) {
     if (error) {
       console.log('[' + chalk.red('×') + ']' + ' failed on image ' + count);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually waiting for each request to complete, nor are you ever invoking the callback.  You need to listen for the `finish` event on the writable stream that you are sending to the pipe.  So, you will want your code to look something like this:

```
async.each(images, function (image, callback) {
  var uri = image.attribs.src;
  var random = (Math.random() * (3 - 1) + 1) | 0;
    var writable = fs.createWriteStream(outFile);
    request(uri).pipe(writable);
    writable.on('finish', callback);
    console.log('[' + chalk.green('✓') + ']' + ' wrote image ' + count);
    count++;
    if (count === commander.max) {
      process.exit(0); 
    }
    sleep.sleep(random);
}, function (error) {
     if (error) {
       console.log('[' + chalk.red('×') + ']' + ' failed on image ' + count);
     }
});
```

See more information here: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Comment: I'm still getting only 9 images when I specify the max as 10. Also, I tried giving an event of on end, but the images were still not finished downloading

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code you are using?

Comment: I updated. The format might be a little off, but that's it for the most part. See anything?

Comment: I don't see you using the callback in your code.  Also, why are you sleeping? What use is this serving? Since node is asynchronous, you should be adding a listener to the 'finish' event and doing your cleanup after completing the pipe.

Comment: Sleep is to pause between each requests. I'm still new to javascript, how should I implement the callback? Thanks for the feedback as well.

Comment: I don't see any need to pause between requests.  Essentially, what your current implementation is doing is invoking all the requests, sleeping for a bit, and then existing before finishing the requests.   To keep things simple, just implement the callback like this: `function() { console.log('I am done'); }`. Also, you should remove the process.exit call.